# Remove last nested list that contains specific element

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a large nested list and I need to do the following:

Find the number of lists that contain a specific element, if that number is more than 2, remove all of those lists after the 2nd.

So a basic example:

```
el = 'ABCfrog'

input = [['ABCdog','a','b'],['ABCfrog','sadg','aseas','ww'],['ABCfrog','dd','ee','ww'],['ABCfrog','dsf','aseas','r','13451v51'],['ABCfrog','3452'],['ABCmouse','xx',],['ABCorange','324213v4']]

output = [['ABCdog','a','b'],['ABCfrog','sadg','aseas','ww'],['ABCfrog','dd','ee','ww'],['ABCmouse','xx',],['ABCorange','324213v4']]
```

Attempt:

```
generic_list = []
for i in input:
    if el in i:
        generic_list.append(i)
number = len(generic_list)

if number>2:
    input.something...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm should work - it keeps count of the number of times the element has been seen as it loops over the sublists, and only appends a sublist to the output if it is one of the first two sublists to contain the element, or doesn't contain the element at all. I think this is the logic that you had in mind if I understand correctly.

```
el = 'ABCfrog'
inputs = [['ABCdog','a','b'], ['ABCfrog','sadg','aseas','ww'], ['ABCfrog','dd','ee','ww'],  ['ABCfrog','dsf','aseas','r','13451v51'], ['ABCfrog','3452'],['ABCmouse','xx',], ['ABCorange','324213v4']]

outputs = []
count = 0
for i in inputs:
    if el in i and count < 2:
        outputs.append(i)
        count += 1
    elif el not in i:
        outputs.append(i)
```

As an aside, notice that I renamed your `input` variable to `inputs`, to avoid overwriting the built-in function `input`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
output = []
counter = 0
for sub_list in input:
    if counter >= 2:
        break
    if el in sub_list:
        counter += 1
        output.append(sub_list)
print(output)
```

Comment: "This should work:" is not an explanation (the other answers are not better in this respect)